# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 running Lineage OS not rebooting properly after `adb reboot` unless USB disconnect

Tags: adb, usb, linux, lineageos, reboot

I am currently facing an issue with my Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 tablet running Lineage OS. Whenever I attempt to reboot the device using the `adb reboot` command through `adb`, it enters a strange hanging state - the screen turns off, and it becomes unresponsive to any further commands. It remains in this state until I physically unplug the USB cable, at which point the tablet restarts and functions normally again. Interestingly, during this state, the `adb` daemon fails to recognize the device, but `lsusb` still detects its presence. I have attempted to restart the USB port/device using `usbreset`,

```
sudo usbreset 18d1:4ee7
```

but within the `dmesg` log, I get attempts with several errors saying `usb 1-1: device descriptor read/64, error -71` followed by finally with `usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle` (full error output [here](https://pastebin.com/E4PpBNgb)). The terminal output is

```
Resetting Galaxy Tab 2 ... failed [No such device]
```

And the computer (in my case, a Raspberry Pi Zero W) does not recognize the Android device anymore until I disconnect the USB. I have tried restarting the RPi but still no luck, since I assume a complete "power cycle" would trigger it since it only operates after disconnection or reset of the 5V connection in the USB.

One hacky solution I have contemplating was creating a switch with the GPIO pins as a variant from this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/104564/347607), but I am still optimistic for a software-only solution before I start throwing hardware into the mix.

Here are some additional details that might be useful:

```
Tablet model: Samsung Galaxy Tab 2

adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release: 7.1.2
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk: 25
adb shell getprop ro.build.flavor: lineage_espressowifi-userdebug
adb shell getprop ro.build.description:
espresso10wifixx-user 4.2.2 JDQ39 P5110XXDML1 release-keys

$adb --version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.2-debian
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I own multiple Samsung devices, but Samsung uses a custom boot process. It uses more like a custom uboot image than a standard Android boot process. Second, you will need a Samsung driver. From what I saw, you are using a Linux machine and Debian-based.

But I can see that you are using an Android 7 image. That device was shipped with an Android 4 system that could boot Lineage OS 10.

Comment: Hi, I tried editing this post based on my understanding since I can't understand the meaning of "y" used here (Is it a French pronoun?). If I accidentally changed the meaning, feel free to [edit] and improve it, thanks.